# How to make right side of my layout clickable?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F2F2F2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/service_icon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_of_service"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/service_icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#4D4D4D"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expand_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/name_of_service"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/down_arrow" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_descr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test_back"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:textColor="#666666" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I would like to make whole right side where imageview is placed clickable not only imageview. I decided to put my imageview into framelayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F2F2F2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/service_icon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_of_service"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/service_icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#4D4D4D"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/click_area"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/name_of_service"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/expand_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/down_arrow" />
        </FrameLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_descr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test_back"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:textColor="#666666" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then override click event:

```
holder.frameLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    Log.i("m","sjn");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But as I see I can click only the bottom part of my layout. This layout is used like view of my RecyclerView item and when I click on the right side I will show hidden linearlayout like this:

```
holder.showHideBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (invisible) {
                holder.layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                invisible = false;
                holder.showHideBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_up_arrow);
            } else {
                holder.layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                invisible = true;
                holder.showHideBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_arrow);
            }

        });
```

Maybe somebody can help me with my problem? I tried to use constraint layout and I didn't manage to solve my problem. Then I tried to use `weight` for this task but it didn't help me :(

### UPDATE

After adding click handler for both framelayout and imageview:
[image]

Comment: Try to write `onClick` listener for both, `FrameLayout` and your `ImageView`.

Comment: Can you explain more what exactly are you trying to achieve here ? You have a single imageview on right and then the layout covers the whole area what exactly you are meant by right side ? Maybe share an image of what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Umair, right now I have this - click on imageview and hidden linear layout becomes visible. My imageview is too small and some of users can't tap on it from the first time. I decided to make small part of the main linear layout clickable, not only imageview.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko you need to use your framelayout as your imagview. Add click listener to your framelayout not to imageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem via constraint_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F2F2F2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.7"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/testClick"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/service_icon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_of_service"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/service_icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#4D4D4D"
            android:textSize="14sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/testClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#F2F2F2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/relLay"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/relLay"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expand_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/down_arrow" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_descr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/test_back"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/relLay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
            android:textColor="#666666" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

maybe it will help someone else. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to write `onClick` listener for both, `FrameLayout` and your `ImageView`, because your `ImageView` now covers your `FrameLayout` and you have only this small area which is not covered by `ImageView`. This should help.

Comment: I have added picture of the results of my work, can you check it?

Comment: Did you try my answer? Does it help?

Comment: Are you sure that your `FrameLayout` is in that place exactly?

Comment: yes sure, I did it like it have to be, but I can click only imageview.

Comment: Can you show your code of `onClick` of both `FrameLayout` and `ImageView`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193001/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-asset-bekbossynov).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your click Listener to your frame layout not on `imageview`. In that case your `frameLayout` will work as your `imageView`.

```
    holder.frameLayout.setOnClickListener(view -> {

 if (invisible) {
                holder.layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                invisible = false;
                holder.showHideBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_up_arrow);
            } else {
                holder.layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                invisible = true;
                holder.showHideBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_arrow);
            }

        });
```

Comment: I have added picture of the results of my work, can you check it?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko if you add handler for framelayout then don't add click listener for imageview.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko remove click handler for imageview, Only one will be enough

Comment: I have removed click handler, but I can show hidden elements only when I click on imageview

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko wasn't it the case you wanted ?. I am confused now :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `Framelayout` and set `ImageView` like this

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/expand_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/name_of_service"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_start" />
```

Your image will take the whole right side and with `fitEnd` the icon will be placed on bottom side.

Comment: everything acts like picture in my question :(

Comment: Are you sure? I just test it and for me, it works. Be sure to set the onClick listener only in your `ImageView`.